# can't read argv[2] from main function in C

Tags: c, args

I am trying to run java jar using system() function from stdlib.h but I can't print argv[2]
this is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char command[] = "java -jar lans.jar ";
    char space[] = " ";

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        char* option = argv[1];
        strcat(command, option);
        printf(command);
        system(command);
    }
    else if (argc == 4)
    {
        char* option = argv[1];
        strcat(option, space);

        char* ip = argv[2];
        strcat(ip, space);

        char* file = argv[3];
        strcat(file, space);

        strcat(command, option);
        strcat(command, ip);
        strcat(command, file);
        printf(command);
        system(command);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("wrong args\n");
        system(command);
    }
}
```

This is the output

```
PS C:\Users\Josep\Dev\C> .\bin\lans.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
        option                            use
        ------------------------------------------
        -s [target ip] [file name]          send a file (no need to write the full path if the file is in working directory
        -r                                  start receiving files
java -jar lans.jar arg1   arg3
```

argv2 is missing, and I don't know why.

I don't write much C code. Any help?

Comment: You can't concatenate anything onto `command[]` the array is already 'full'. And it is fairly certain you can't concatentate onto `argv[1]` or `argv[2]` either.

Comment: Your code could be simplified (and safer) if you use `snprintf` instead of your `strcat` calls.

Comment: Unrelated, `printf(command);` = terrible idea. That is a recipe for a [buffer overflow exploit](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/43575/183945). *Never* issue `printf` commands without a proper format string, even if that string is just `%s` .

Comment: Begin with say `char syscomm[1024]` and build the string there.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but still if tried to print `char* ip = argv[2];` without concatenating onto it. It prints nothing.  So the main issue isn't about concatenating the command, and the arguments.

Comment: @YousefAli Are you still concatenating to argv[1]?

Comment: @klutt No I am trying now to allocate enough space to hold the full string.

Comment: `char *ip = argv[2]; printf("%s", ip);` will print whatever is in `argv[2]`. If it's empty, then it either was empty before or you modified it in some other part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing where there's no space to write. The buffers in `argv` are exactly as long as they need to be. Or well, that's the only thing you can count on. You can never safely concatenate to them. And in general, it's a good idea to consider them read only.

Here is a snippet to allocate enough for all arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int totlen = 0;
    char *buf;

    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) 
        totlen += strlen(argv[i]) + 1; // +1 for space

    buf = malloc(totlen + 1); // +1 for zero terminator

    if(!buf) exit(1); // If malloc failed

    buf[0] = 0; // Or else first strcat may cause trouble

    for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        strcat(buf, argv[i]);
        strcat(buf, " ");
    }

    printf("%s\n", buf);

    free(buf);
}
```

After this, `buf` will be big enough to hold all arguments passed to the program with a space between each. The program will print all the arguments passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add some extra length to array `command`
2. Use direct value from `argv` to prepare command.

```
char command[1024] = "java -jar lans.jar ";
......
else if (argc == 4) {
    strcat(command, argv[1]);
    strcat(command, space);
    strcat(command, argv[2]);
    strcat(command, space);
    strcat(command, argv[3]);
    printf(command);
    system(command);
}
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, as a thought experiment (there is no rule about it) that `argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, ... are all contiguous in memory...

So you have somewhere in memory the data

```
    // 0 is the '\0' string terminator
    executable.exe0arg10arg20arg30 ...
    ^              ^    ^    ^ argv[3]
    ^              ^    \----  argv[2]
    ^              \---------  argv[1]
    \------------------------  argv[0]
```

and then your code

```
    char* option = argv[1];
    strcat(option, space);
```

Note that the pointers `argv[]` did not change

```
    // 0 is the '\0' string terminator
    executable.exe0arg1 0rg20arg30 ...
    ^              ^    ^    ^ argv[3]
    ^              ^    \----  argv[2]
    ^              \---------  argv[1]
    \------------------------  argv[0]
```

`argv[2]` now point to the `'\0'` string terminator that was put there after the `strcat()` operation

```
    char* ip = argv[2];
```

`ip` also points to a `'\0'` string terminator

Comment: Oh ok this makes sense. I understand now why I can't print `ip`. Thank you